# Proof Verification: No finite set spans $P$, the set of all polynomial functions.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Proof: (by contradiction)

Let $\langle B_i\rangle=P_i$; the set $B_i$ span $P_i$ such that $P_i$ is the set of all polynomials of degree $i$. Suppose there exist a set $S$ such that 
$S:=\{p_i(x)\in B_i \mid p_i(x)\in\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i \text{ where $B_i$ is the basis of } P_i\}$ and $\langle S\rangle=P$. This implies that $\forall p_j(x)\in P$, $p_j(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n c_ip_i(x)$ for some $p_i(x)\in B_i$ and $c_i\in\Bbb{F}$.
However, if $j\geq n+1$ then $p_j(x)\notin \langle\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i \rangle$. Thus, a contradiction. $\Bbb{QED}$

Comment: Where exactly did you prove that no finite set spans $P$?

Comment: $S$ is the assumed arbitrary finite spanning set of $P$, and since there exist $p_j(x)\notin <\cup_{i=1}^{n}B_i>=S$ then $S$ cannot span $P$. Would that be an acceptable argument?

Comment: Note proper MathJax usage, as in my edits to this question. Proper notation is $\langle B_i\rangle = \cdots,$ not $<B_i> = \cdots.$ One writes $A\cap B$ and $A_1\cap \cdots \cap A_n,$ but $\bigcap_{k=1}^n A_k$ rather than $\cap_{k=1}^n A_k.$  Thus $p_j(x)\notin \langle \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i \rangle = S$ rather than $p_j(x)\notin<\cup_{i=1}^n B_i >=S.$ Also, in $$S: = \{p_i(x) \in B_i \mid \text{etc. etc.} \},$$ the $\{\text{curly braces} \}$ are inside of MathJax, not outside. And note the use of \mid. $\qquad$

Comment: Assuming that you are referring to the set of *polynomials* (*which must have a highest degree term*) and not *formal power series* (*which may go on indefinitely*) then use the distinction between the two to your advantage.  As any polynomial is of finite degree, and any finite collection of polynomials must have some largest finite degree appearing...

Answer (score 1):

You have not given any proof that no finite set spans $P$.  Your argument is very difficult to understand, but it appears you have argued that one particular finite set $S$ does not span $P$.  That is not enough: you need to start with some *completely arbitrary* finite set $S$ which spans $P$ and get a contradiction.  You cannot assume $S$ has any specific definition as you have done.

Comment: can I add to the argument that $B_i$ is an arbitrary basis for the set $P_i$?

Comment: I would suggest you completely abandon your idea of using bases $B_i$, as it is leading you in unproductive directions and causing you to make unclear, incorrect arguments.